# Dynamic bootstrap "active" selection for pages

Tags: javascript, navigation, navbar

I need to select a navigation item as active when the page loads.  This issue is within a bootstrap framework. I know how to do this in PhP.

I have multiple pages and want to keep the navigation in a PhP include. Currently, I have to have the navigation code links in each page. When the user selects "About" I want the About nav item active and dynamically selected. I would like use javascript and the "addClass" function.

I'm not a high-level javascript developer, but can do some basic functions, etc.

I have been searching and haven't found anything that works for me.

Thanks

Ted

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not exactly sure what you're asking, but I assume you want the Javascript to add the .active class to a nav bar link when that url is the active one. You could create a utility function which analyzes the window's url and matches that to the correct tab. for instance:

```
(function(){
   var host = "www.yourdomain.com/plus/whatever/else"; //the default domain
   var state = window.location.href.subString(host.length - 1); //extract state

   var stateMap = {
      someStateName: 'nav-selector-value'
   };

   var navElement = document.getElementById(stateMap[state]);
   navElement.className += " active"; //make sure you have a space before
})();
```

This is just a quick and dirty example. You'll have to use some regex if your states get more complex.